# Could an enum be used as a class?

Tags: java

I was reading through the [Java Oracle Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), and I saw an example of enum in use:

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS   (4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH   (5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS    (6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER (1.9e+27,   7.1492e7),
    SATURN  (5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS  (8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE (1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    private final double mass;   // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters
    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    private double mass() { return mass; }
    private double radius() { return radius; }

    // universal gravitational constant  (m3 kg-1 s-2)
    public static final double G = 6.67300E-11;

    double surfaceGravity() {
        return G * mass / (radius * radius);
    }
    double surfaceWeight(double otherMass) {
        return otherMass * surfaceGravity();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Planet <earth_weight>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        double earthWeight = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double mass = earthWeight/EARTH.surfaceGravity();
        for (Planet p : Planet.values())
           System.out.printf("Your weight on %s is %f%n",
                             p, p.surfaceWeight(mass));
    }
}
```

I always thought that enums were sets of related constants that were usually used outside of a class, but this example shows enum being used as if it was a class, with its own methods and constructors. I know that it is an enum because of the "enum" in the class declaration. Could an enum be used like a class? What is the difference between a class and an enum if they are this similar? What are some good uses for enums that act like a standard class?

Thanks

Comment: **The enum declaration defines a class (called an enum type)** from same link you added

Comment: Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Could I get some clarification on what you mean by the enum declaration defining a class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720166/using-enum-as-a-class-in-java

Comment: @Taschi So are you saying that it can be used like a class?

Comment: @pdsla112, with the caveat that you cannot invoke its constructor, yes, it can, because it essentially *is* a class.

Comment: @emotionlessbananas I have read the link that you have provided, but the example in that question is different from what I am asking, in the sense that, the code in my question quite explicitly has "enum" in place of "class" and acts like a class. Please correct me if I am confused.

Comment: @Taschi Okay. Since it cannot invoke its constructor, I'm assuming that means that it cannot be instantiated into an object? Also, if it is not ideal for using like a class, is there absolutely no use in using it like a class?

Comment: @pdsla112, by definition an enum has a limited number of instances (e. g. NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST in an enum called Direction). That is the one thing differentiating an enum from any other class. Of course there is no point in using an enum as a regular class, because you can just use a regular class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `enum` is very like a normal class, except that instances are defined at compile time and are guaranteed to be singletons, and they may not `extend` anything.

However, they can:

- have instance fields, that may be final or not (although in conventional usage they are immutable, it is not required)
- have class (`static`) fields (although they must be declared after the instances)
- have getters/setters for fields
- have constructors (just not public ones)
- implement interfaces
- be decorated with annotations

Answer (score 1):

The `enum` keyword is a language construct that essentially creates a (final) class which extends `java.lang.Enum` and forces you to define the (possibly empty) set of all named instances upfront, inside the enum definition.
So the answer is definitely yes; actually, you can't really use it in any other way.

Even if you don't add any logic to it, it will still be class:

```
enum Day { SUNDAY, MONDAY... }
```

This already provides you with static methods like `Day.valueOf()` and instance methods such as like `Day.SUNDAY.ordinal()`, `name()` or `compareTo()`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use enum as a class, you can use it in below way.

```
public class Weather {

     public enum Season {
         WINTER,
         SPRING,
         SUMMER,
         FALL
     }
     private final Season season;

     private static final List < Weather > listWeather = new ArrayList < Weather > ();

     private Weather(Season season) {
         this.season = season;
     }

     public Season getSeason() {
         return season;
     }

     static {

         for (Season season: Season.values()) {
             listWeather.add(new Weather(season));
         }
     }

     public static ArrayList < Weather > getWeatherList() {
         return listWeather;
     }
     public String toString() {
         return season;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The main difference between an enum and a standard class is in the restrictions: All instances of an enum must be declared at compile time; all fields must be final and the class cannot be extended.

Comment: Would you not recommend using enums in place of standard classes?

Comment: Not "all fields must be final", only enum constants are implicitly public static and final. Of course, any non-final (static or instance) field becomes global mutable state, so it should be avoided at all costs -- but there's no restriction in place.

Comment: Incorrect!!! Fields do not have to be final - you can freely change them if they have setters or are public

Comment: @pdsla112 If you find that even with these restrictions, the class still does everything you require it to, then yes an enum is probably more appropriate than a standard class.